# Is there a way to exclude an app that requires pedometer from the App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, core-motion, pedometer

I'm working on an app that requires step counting.
There are several devices that don't support this feature (for example in my iPad mini 2, `CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable()` returns `false`).

Since the app heavily relies on the pedometer, I'd like to make it unavailable to download for unsupported devices.

I would expect to find a pedometer-related entry in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uirequireddevicecapabilities) of `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`, but there is none.

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: There isn't actually a "pedometer" in a device. Your _app_ is the "pedometer"! What the device has is an accelerometer and a gyroscope, and these are used by Core Motion's motion processor to deduce from certain forms of regular motion that the user is stepping. So it might suffice to block on those.

Comment: But I should add that Apple doesn't really want you using the required device capabilities this way. They would prefer that, if your app discovers that capabilities that it needs are missing, it should just fail gracefully at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it was very useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to make an app unavailable for download on the basis of `CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable()`. The preferred method would be to display a notice to the user once downloaded, that their device does not support the required functionality.